# Calculate percentage for each value of a column sql

Tags: sql

I want to rewrite this sql query so that he shows a record with 0 for the corresponding age range if there are no matches and I want that he counts the percentages for each value of Member instead of the '0' at this moment, can anyone help me how I can achieve this?

```
SELECT COUNT(Name) * 100 / 
    (select COUNT(*) from 'cities'
    WHERE city= 'Hoeselt' AND Member = '0' ) AS 'perc', 
    CASE 
        WHEN age <= 30 THEN '18-30'
        WHEN age <= 50 THEN '31-50'
        ELSE '50+'
    END AS age, COUNT(*) AS n 
FROM 'cities' 
    WHERE city= 'Hoeselt' AND elected='yes' AND Member= '0'
    GROUP BY CASE
        WHEN age <= 30 THEN '18-30'
        WHEN age <= 50 THEN '31-50'
        ELSE '50+'
    END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to be certain that this will work for you without the DDL.
This is a great tool for helping people give you the best solution.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6

```
;WITH AgeCat AS
(
    SELECT   MinAge = 18
            ,MaxAge = 30
            ,Descr  = '18-30'   UNION ALL
    SELECT 31, 49, '31-49'      UNION ALL
    SELECT 50, 200, '50+'
)
SELECT   DISTINCT
         C.Descr
        ,Perc   = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY 0) / COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY A.Descr) * 100
FROM AgeCat A
JOIN Cities C   ON C.Age BETWEEN A.MinAge AND A.MaxAge
WHERE city = 'Hoeselt'
AND elected = 'yes'
AND Member = '0'
```

Comment: COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY 0) / COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY A.Descr) * 100 was changed to COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY 0) / COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY C.Descr) * 100. Sorry about that. Try again

Comment: I think you can use `OVER ()` instead of `OVER (PARTITION BY 0)`

Comment: anyone how knows how I can do that with the member? I want the percentage for each value of member

Comment: @user735646, it isn't clear from the code you have made available what a member is. But the principle should work if you adapt it.

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this is to use a CTE to define the age group.  Next select all the age groups as a "driver" table, left joining in the cities information.  Then, you have the age group even when there are no matches:

```
with c as (
    select c.*,
           (CASE WHEN age <= 30 THEN '18-30'
                 WHEN age <= 50 THEN '31-50'
                 ELSE '50+'
             END) as agegrp
    from cities
   )
select COUNT(Name) * 100 / (select COUNT(*) from cities WHERE city= 'Hoeselt' AND Member = '0') as perc,
       driver.agegrp,
       COUNT(*) as n
from (select distinct agegrp from c) as driver left outer join
     c
     on driver.agegrp = c.agegrp
group by driver.agegrp
```